# Inequality with exponent from (0,1)

Tags: elementary-functions

Let $x,y>0$, $a\in(0,1)$. Is true the following inequality
$(x+y)^a\le x^a+y^a$?

Comment: Jensen's inequality?

Comment: Yes, it is true. Try to prove it by fixing $y$ and differentiating w.r.t. $x$.